# Nginx microcaching wordpress, why is returning bypass?

Tags: nginx

recently I had to setup AWS ASG environment for Wordpress application. This wordpress is a very common one.

The environment in pre and pro is equal and also the behavior of both. My infrastructure have:

- 1 ASG
- 1 ALB
- m3.medium EC2 instances
- Memcached cluster
- RDS MySQL
- S3 for static content

Stack is a common Nginx / Php 5.6 FPM with microcaching enabled and W3TC to setup cache for database and other stuff.

My nginx.conf is like (I will hide the domain name)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 65536;
        use epoll;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    log_format  main  '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server_names_hash_max_size 1024;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    keepalive_timeout  65 20;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_buffers 256 8k;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain test/html text/xml text/css image/x-icon image/bmp application/atom+xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/pdf application/postscript application/rtf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint application/msword application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml;

    fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:100m inactive=60m;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    #limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.pre.d/*.conf;

}
```

An example of virtual host will be:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name   domain.org.dev;
    return        301  https://www.domain.org.dev$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/domain;
        index index.html index.htm index index.php;

        server_name www.domain.org;

        error_page 503 @maintenance;
        location @maintenance {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
        }

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
               rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
        }

        location / {
                if (-f $document_root/503.html) {
                    return 503;
                }
                try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                port_in_redirect off;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        }

         location ~ .php$ {
                #include global/wp-security.conf;
                include global/php.conf;
                include global/wp-microcache.conf;
        }

        location ~ /.ht(access|passwd) {
                deny  all;
        }
        location ~ /.git {
                deny  all;
        }
        location ~ /.svn {
                deny  all;
        }
        include global/static-content.conf;
}
```

the most important part is the wp-microcache.conf. Honestly, I took a look on this website to setup my configuration because was very well explained (https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wordpress-nginx/blob/master/global/server/fastcgi-cache.conf)

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;

fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;


set $skip_cache 0;

if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/wp-json/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
fastcgi_cache microcache;
fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
```

So I ran BlazeMeter test on Wordpress, just GETS so I was expecting pretty success around HITs. However, after analyze results I noticed that many URLS from Worpress were BYPASSING the cache.  Then I understood why I saw so many php-fpm process doing stuff in the EC2 meanwhile test was running.

Anyway, the point is, If I test the Wordpress home (no matter if by curl or navigator):

```
$ curl -I https://www.domain.org.dev
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 14:29:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Link: <https://www.domain.org.dev/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <https://www.domain.org.dev/>; rel=shortlink
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 13:53:05 GMT
Link: <https://www.domain.org.dev/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <https://www.domain.org.dev/>; rel=shortlink
X-Cache: HIT
```

Nevertheless, If I requests other url from the same Wordpress:

```
$ curl -I https://www.domain.org.dev/about-us
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 14:29:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 14:18:58 GMT
Location: https://www.domain.org.dev/about-us/
X-Cache: BYPASS
```

Why this different behavior? What things can I inspect in order to fix this? I'm kind of lost here. I suspect there is nothing related with plugins or other stuff.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to statement `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` which is taking a page path (other than home page) and converting it in a query string i.e. `q=my-non-home-page`. Then you have following block to bypass the query string caching,

```
if ($query_string != "") {
set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

I will suggest you update the statement to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

You can put debugging mechanism like following which will can help you to highlight the root cause of the problem.

```
    set $cache_bypass_reason "NONE";
    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and URLs with a query string should always skip cache
    if ($request_method = POST) {
       set $skip_cache 1;
       set $cache_bypass_reason "POST";
     }
    if ($query_string != "") {
      set $skip_cache 1;
      set $cache_bypass_reason "QUERY-STRING";
    }
    etc
```

Do any path rewrite if needed, i.e.

```
rewrite ^/sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml$ "/index.php?xml_sitemap=params=$2" last;
```